# Removing active class if clicking active link a second time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across a question that wanted to add an active link to the currently clicked menu item.

The solution was to add:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Now how can we remove the active class if we click the active link a second time? I'm guessing we need to use toggleClass() but I haven't been able to make it work. Note only one link should have active class at a time.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $a = $(this);
  $a.toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I typed "sibling" instead of "siblings". Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ/6/

Comment: The `<a>` are not sibling in your code. You probably should have linked to this from the start.

Comment: Ok I fixed it with `$a.toggleClass('active').closest("li").siblings().find("a").removeClass('active');` - thank you again! lastly, why do we need `e.preventDefault()` here? Would be better if you explain this.

Comment: The `e.preventDefault()` keeps the browser from actually going to that link.

Answer (score 2):

Use `toggleClass()` then:

```
$(this).toggleClass("active");
```

Code:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("a").not(this).removeClass("active");

});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FH47P/2/)

Comment: Then how do I remove active class from siblings? Only one link should have active class.

Comment: one link will have active class

Comment: No look here: http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ/5/ .. if you click two links both will have active class.

Comment: In latest demo class won't remove if you click a second time.

Comment: Thanks @Popnoodles i realized my self that it was not working updated :http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ

Answer (score 0):

Check if current link is `active` then add/remove `active` `class` based on that, Try this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var isActive = $this.hasClass('active');
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    isActive ? $this.removeClass("active") : $this.addClass("active");
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ/7/)

Answer (score 0):

here you have a simple answer:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
$("a").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});

$("nav").on("mouseleave", function() {
$("nav").find("a").removeClass("active");   
});
```

What this does is, when your mouse leaves the `nav` it will automatically remove you `active` class on `a`. here you have the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A6dqQ/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("active")) {
        $this.removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $("a").removeClass("active");
        $this.addClass("active");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnbk/kG5HY)